# MutationObserver - Detect change in div childs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mutation-observers

I need to call an action when there are changes in the DOM in the children of a parent DIV. I saw that there is this method (MutationObserver) but I tried to add it on WORDPRESS and I can't print on the console even when there are changes. I wanted to do it through class because the id is dynamic from the parent div.

I am trying this code on a page.

```
    //  select the target 
alert('This is Test 1');

var target = document.querySelector('#mmp-map-2b40f571');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
      alert('This is a test 2');
  });
});

// configuration of the observer
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };


observer.observe(target, config);

/* mais tarde você pode parar de observar
observer.disconnect();*/
```

The action only runs when I open the page and whenever there are changes in the levels below this div it does not enter the action. In the image link you can see the JavaScript debbug in the inspect

https://www.screencast.com/t/9UWSLh4D4r

I appreciate help :)

Comment: Add `subtree:true` to config.

Comment: Works like a charm. Many thanks wOxxOm